# Improve the performance with cte ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I have a performance issue in the following script.

At the beginning, the script runs around a few second.

Nowadays, it needs run around 3 mins.

I think the most of the reason is the `TransactionSendQueue` table, which has over 3 million rows at this moment. In the "ctetran", I need to find out the latest record and compare with the temp table.

I try to add different index, but it cannot improve it even slower. Any suggestions on how to improve the performance.

```
WITH ctetran AS --the lastest transaction
(
    SELECT 
        Tran_ID, 
        Field2, 
        Field3, 
        Field4, 
        Field5, 
        Field6, 
        Field7, 
        Field8, 
        Field9, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Tran_ID
                           ORDER BY LastUpdate DESC) AS rn
    FROM 
        TransactionSendQueue
    WHERE 
        STATUS = '1'
)  --where 1 mean complete
UPDATE temp
SET STATUS = CASE
                WHEN temp.f2 = cte.Field2
                     AND temp.f3 = cte.Field3
                     AND temp.f4 = cte.Field4
                     AND temp.f5 = cte.Field5
                     AND temp.f6 = cte.Field6
                     AND temp.f7 = cte.Field7
                     AND temp.f8 = cte.Field8
                     AND temp.f9 = cte.Field9
                   THEN '2' -- where 2 mean skip
                ELSE '3' --where 3 mean ready to execute
             END
FROM #TempTran temp
INNER JOIN ctetran cte ON temp.Tran_ID = cte.Tran_ID
                       AND cte.rn = 1;
```

The table design:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TransactionSendQueue]
(
    [Batch_ID]   [CHAR](20) NOT NULL, 
    [Tran_ID]    [VARCHAR](20) NOT NULL,  
    [Field2]     [VARBINARY](100) NULL, 
    [Field3]     [VARBINARY](100) NULL, 
    [Field4]     [VARBINARY](100) NULL, 
    [Field5]     [VARBINARY](100) NULL, 
    [Field6]     [VARBINARY](100) NULL, 
    [Field7]     [VARBINARY](100) NULL, 
    [Field8]     [VARBINARY](100) NULL, 
    [Field9]     [VARBINARY](100) NULL, 
    [LastUpdate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL, 
    [STATUS]     [INTEGER] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TransactionSendQueue] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Batch_ID], [Tran_ID])
);
```

Comment: For performance related question we need to see the execution plan using "Paste The Plan"

Comment: The easy thing to try with a CTE is to materialise it into a temp table. So put your cte query results into a temp table, and then carry out whatever action you normally do on the cte results. This frequently solves cte performance issues. However is the basic cte query is still slow, then we need the execution plan.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks. It is hard to share the execution plan. I am trying to convert it to temp table and test it again. thanks

Comment: As I said use "Paste The Plan" - its for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Please add definitions for indexes, as well as definitions for the temp table, also share the query plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One core principle when doing SQL queries with mutliple steps needs to be: **eliminate as much data as possible as early as possible**. Your CTE loads all rows from TransactionSendQueue, when you only want the latest transaction per Tran_ID. The more data that's being handled, the higher risk of data loaded being written to disk, which is extremely detrimental to performance. The more data that's written to disk, the worse the impact is. You can view your execution plan to check if this is the case but I'd say it's likely considering the execution time.

The CTE should only return one row per row that could possibly be updated in your #TempTran table. You can use an additional CTE to retrieve the latest update first, and then use that information in your ctetran to reduce the amount of data (rows) being search ed through in the update statement.

```
WITH LatestTran AS --the lastest transaction
(
    SELECT 
        Tran_ID, 
        MAX(LastUpdate) AS LastUpdate
    FROM 
        TransactionSendQueue
    WHERE 
        STATUS = '1' --where 1 mean complete
    GROUP BY
        Tran_ID
), ctetran AS
(
    SELECT 
        Tran_ID, 
        Field2, 
        Field3, 
        Field4, 
        Field5, 
        Field6, 
        Field7, 
        Field8, 
        Field9
    FROM 
        TransactionSendQueue TSQ
    INNER JOIN LatestTran LT ON 
        TSQ.Tran_ID = LT.Tran_ID AND 
        TSQ.LastUpdate = LT.LastUpdate
)


UPDATE temp
SET STATUS = CASE
                WHEN temp.f2 = cte.Field2
                     AND temp.f3 = cte.Field3
                     AND temp.f4 = cte.Field4
                     AND temp.f5 = cte.Field5
                     AND temp.f6 = cte.Field6
                     AND temp.f7 = cte.Field7
                     AND temp.f8 = cte.Field8
                     AND temp.f9 = cte.Field9
                   THEN '2' -- where 2 mean skip
                ELSE '3' --where 3 mean ready to execute
             END
FROM #TempTran temp
INNER JOIN ctetran cte ON temp.Tran_ID = cte.Tran_ID
```

How big performance increase this will be is dependent on how many Batch_ID you have per Tran_ID, the more the bigger perfomance boost.

If the query is still running slow, you could also look into using an index for the LastUpdate column in the TransactionSendQueue table, since the query is now using that in a join statement.

Please let me know how much the query time is reduced, would be interesting to know.